# AVPlayerViewController - What is this red icon on tvOS?

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

[image]

We're using AVPlayerViewController on tvOS and intermittently get this icon. It's not our icon - it's from AVPlayerViewController. Does anyone know what state produces it?:

Comment: Is it the "Not allowed" icon, related to Settings -> General -> Restrictions -> Allowed Content?

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting it though. There are no restrictions on my AppleTV atm. Also, we're only playing two types of content and most play fine - tvOS shouldn't know anything about the content.

Answer (score 1):

It means your player item has an error and cannot be used. Check player.currentItem.error. Your app should observe the error property and present an alert and/or take other action.